# How to show datetime object when using groupby and resample in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 20) for n in range(430)]})

df['VALUE1'] = [random.randrange(110, 140) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.randrange(50, 60) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE3'] = [random.randrange(80, 100) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE4'] = [random.randrange(30, 50) for n in range(430)]

df['MODEL'] = [random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]

df['SOLD'] = [random.randrange(0, 2) for n in range(430)]

df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION'] == 1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2, 3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')

df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
# df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')


# Create DAY Night columns only-------------------------------------------------------------------------
def cycle_day_period(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, midnight='00:00:00', start_of_morning='06:00:00',
                     start_of_afternoon='13:00:00',
                     start_of_evening='18:00:00', end_of_evening='23:00:00', start_of_night='24:00:00'):
    bins = [midnight, start_of_morning, start_of_afternoon, start_of_evening, end_of_evening, start_of_night]
    labels = ['Night', 'Morning', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Night']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(dataframe),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['CYCLE_PART'] = cycle_day_period(df['TIME'], '00:00:00', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00')
```

I resample my time series depending on a condition using the following script.

```
freq = {'Night': '30min', 'Morning': '15min'}
out = (df.groupby('CYCLE_PART')
         .apply(lambda g: g.resample(freq[g.name], on='DATE_TIME').mean())
         .reset_index()
       )
```

But, when I print its output neither **DATE_TIME** nor **TIME** is visible. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try `out = (df.set_index('DATE_TIME').groupby('CYCLE_PART').apply(lambda g: g.resample(freq[g.name]).mean()).reset_index())` ? Because for me your solution working well.

Comment: @jezrael which version of Pandas you have and which IDE do you use? Somehow it does not work for me with PyCharm IDE and Pandas 1.5.3. Your code also worked for me thanks

Comment: I use oldier `1.2.4` in spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is create `DatetimeIndex` first, so possible omit `on` parameter:

```
out = (df.set_index('DATE_TIME')
         .groupby('CYCLE_PART')
         .apply(lambda g: g.resample(freq[g.name]).mean())
         .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. Here is an update of what you did:

```
out = (df.groupby(['CYCLE_PART', pd.Grouper(key='DATE_TIME', freq='1min'), 'TIME'], as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda g: g.resample(freq[g.name[0]], on='DATE_TIME').mean(numeric_only=True))
     )

out = out.reset_index()
out['TIME'] = out['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
```

which gives:

```
     level_0           DATE_TIME    ID  VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3  VALUE4  MODEL  \
0          0 2022-11-01 06:00:00   6.0   110.0    56.0    92.0    40.0    2.0   
1          1 2022-11-01 06:15:00  19.0   132.0    55.0    82.0    37.0    2.0   
2          2 2022-11-01 06:30:00   9.0   130.0    50.0    87.0    31.0    2.0   
3          3 2022-11-01 07:00:00   5.0   118.0    52.0    95.0    31.0    1.0   
4          4 2022-11-01 07:15:00  17.0   125.0    56.0    81.0    48.0    1.0   
..       ...                 ...   ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    ...   
425      425 2022-11-06 21:30:00   7.0   132.0    58.0    94.0    39.0    1.0   
426      426 2022-11-06 22:00:00  12.0   126.0    53.0    87.0    41.0    1.0   
427      427 2022-11-06 22:00:00   8.0   129.0    52.0    96.0    34.0    2.0   
428      428 2022-11-06 22:30:00   9.0   114.0    50.0    98.0    45.0    1.0   
429      429 2022-11-06 23:00:00   7.0   110.0    50.0    96.0    35.0    2.0   

     SOLD  INSPECTION      TIME  
0     1.0         1.0  06:00:00  
1     0.0         1.0  06:15:00  
2     0.0         1.0  06:30:00  
3     1.0         1.0  07:00:00  
4     0.0         1.0  07:15:00  
..    ...         ...       ...  
425   1.0         6.0  21:30:00  
426   1.0         6.0  22:00:00  
427   1.0         6.0  22:00:00  
428   1.0         6.0  22:30:00  
429   0.0         6.0  23:00:00  

[430 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: 1 ) Could you explain the difference in your code please? I did not understand the 1 minute pd.grouper part. 2) Also, is there any way to get rid of old index as being added as new column? when I write reset_index(drop=True), DATE_TIME disappears

Comment: @dspractician 1) Basically, I added pd.Grouper(key='DATE_TIME', freq='1min') to the groupby key to make sure that DATE_TIME is included in the resulting index. After that, it is exactly what you did. 2) You cannot reset_index(drop=True) because DATE_TIME is the index. THis is why it disappears.